# Permission Denial: Accessing service ComponentInfo

Tags: android

I am using

```
<permission
        android:name="com.qualcomm.permission.USE_QCRIL_MSG_TUNNEL"
        android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem" />
```

this permission in my manifest file but i am reciving following error as Access Denied.

```
Permission Denial: Accessing service ComponentInfo{
com.qualcomm.qcrilmsgtunnel/com.qualcomm.qcrilmsgtunnel.QcrilMsgTunnelService
} from pid=4811,
uid=10082 requires com.qualcomm.permission.USE_QCRIL_MSG_TUNNEL
```

Can anybody tell me why i am getting this access denied error.

Answer (score 0):

`signatureOrSystem` means you need run the code in System or in a apk signed with system certificate .

Comment: I am running app as system app. I have psushed apk in /system/app/ folder

Comment: app in /system/app not mean System uid nor system certificate. it is just a folder.

Comment: where to find system certificate so i can sign the apk? i have flashed device & I have used 4.4.2 ROM for nexus.

Comment: after adding android:sharedUserId="system" in manifest, i didn't see app listed in Apps settings.

Comment: you can not get other one's certificate if other not shared it, that is why it called ~certificate~

Comment: that means i have to create my own custom ROM is it?

Comment: too far from your question. basically you can not use 'signatureOrSystem' level permission if you not building a ROM.